# Accordeon does not open - except when i click "back"-button on browser

Tags: javascript

this is my second try to ask this question. Last time, the admin closed the subject because he thought that it was some link-building try or whatever.
He thought the link i posted was from a gaming site - but that's absolutely wrong! It's about Campervans, and it has nothing to do with link-building.
So i hope this time i am a bit more lucky, because i really need your help:

On the website called camperhero (a German site, this time no link), i am using an accordeon.

When i enter the site and try to click the accordeon (below "Das CamperHero 1x1 für Australien"), it does not open. Only the url changes and adds a /#collapse7 at the end.

But the strange thing is: When i move on to another page of this website, and after that click the "back" button of my browser, i can open the accordeon.

I don't understand why it only works after having used the "back"-button!

Maybe you have an idea?

Thank you for your help,
Peter from Germany

Edit: Dev-tools shows me an error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e is not a function
at bootstrap.min.js:6
at bootstrap.min.js:6
```

So for some reason, JS does not load, i suppose. When i go to another page and hit the back button, the error-message disappears and the accordeon opens.

I am using js for bootstrap, the code looks like this:

```
<script async src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script async src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Does that help you?

Comment: Just linking to a web site and asking us to debug it for you will get this question closed also I'm afraid. You have to narrow down the problem and provide [mcve] of the code that is giving you trouble.

Comment: Hi Peter, as a general rule most folks won't follow links to unknown websites (we're web devs, we know how sketchy the net can be even when it's sincere).  Beyond that, it sounds like you're using some sort of URL hash to trigger your JS? That being the case, I would set up a console.log() on the script that reads the URL and see if it's being triggered when the back button is hit.

Comment: Could you post the code that you're using here? I know it'll be hard to replicate a back button feature -- but if we can see the specific code that's going wonky we'd have a good chance of debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution now, maybe this can help someone else:
The issues was caused by adding "async" to the script:

```
<script async src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script async src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

After having removed this, it is working fine.